# Prove $a_n = \sin(n\pi /2)$ does not converge to $0$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

> Not sure how to prove that $a_n = \sin(n\pi /2)$ doesn't converge to $0$.

Prove by contradiction? How do I assume that the sequence converges to $0$ since if I do the partial sums it does end up adding to $0$.

Comment: **Hint:** Consider the subsequences $\{t_n\}$ and $\{u_n\}$ defined by $t_n=\sin(n\pi)$ and $u_n=\sin((4n+1)\pi/2)$ which have distinct finite limits $0$ and $1$ respectively.

Comment: How do partial sums come into it? Are you interested in showing $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\ne0$ or that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ does not converge to 0?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$a_n=\left\{0,1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,...\right\}$$